# PHP: Generate Laravel Paginator Secure (HTTPS) Links

Tags: laravel, https, paginator

I'm developing an app using Laravel 4.2 over HTTPS with secure routes and redirects. I'm using Paginator to paginate results, but the links rendered in the view points to the http pages, how can we force Paginator to generate https links?

Answer (score 29):

I had this issue today and found this global solution.

In your AppServiceProvider::boot method you can add the following to force https on pagination links

```
$this->app['request']->server->set('HTTPS','on');
```

Comment: This also works for any other link, so I was able exchange it for `\URL::forceScheme('https')` which seem to ignore pagination. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If your current page is served over HTTPS, then the pagination URLs generated should use that schema.

However if you're using a proxy that does not pass the correct headers, the `Request` class responsible for determining if the connection is secure, might not report it as such. To determine if the request is detected as secure use `Request::secure()`. If that returns `false`, try using [Laravel Trusted Proxies](https://github.com/fideloper/TrustedProxy).

If that does not work you can force the pagination URLs with `setBaseUrl` as follows:

```php
$results->paginate();
$results->setBaseUrl('https://' . Request::getHttpHost() . '/' . Request::path());
```

Comment: For Laravel 5.1, setPath can be used instead of setBaseUrl

Answer (score 0):

Add a custom presenter `ZurbPresenter.php` in `app/helpers/` (you can place it inside other directory provided its path is included in to `ClassLoader::addDirectories()`):

```
<?php
class ZurbPresenter extends Illuminate\Pagination\Presenter {

    /**
     * Get HTML wrapper for a page link.
     *
     * @param  string  $url
     * @param  int  $page
     * @param  string  $rel
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPageLinkWrapper($url, $page, $rel = null)
    {
        $rel = is_null($rel) ? '' : ' rel="'.$rel.'"';

        if (strpos($url, "http://") === 0) {
            $url = "https://" . ltrim($url, "http://");
        }

        return '<li><a href="'.$url.'"'.$rel.'>'.$page.'</a></li>';
    }

    /**
     * Get HTML wrapper for disabled text.
     *
     * @param  string  $text
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDisabledTextWrapper($text)
    {
        return '<li class="disabled"><span>'.$text.'</span></li>';
    }

    /**
     * Get HTML wrapper for active text.
     *
     * @param  string  $text
     * @return string
     */
    public function getActivePageWrapper($text)
    {
        return '<li class="active"><span>'.$text.'</span></li>';
    }

}
```

Notice the `getPageLinkWrapper()` has a logic to replace `http` by `https`.

Create a view file to use the presenter. Inside `app/views` create a file `zurb_pagination.php` with following content:

```
<?php
    $presenter = new ZurbPresenter($paginator);

    $trans = $environment->getTranslator();
?>

<?php if ($paginator->getLastPage() > 1): ?>
    <ul class="pager">
        <?php
            echo $presenter->getPrevious($trans->trans('pagination.previous'));

            echo $presenter->getNext($trans->trans('pagination.next'));
        ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Finally change your app config to use the new presenter in `app\config/view.php` for pagination:

```
'pagination' => '_zurb_pagination_simple',
```

I use a similar approach for my website and you can verify it's working [here](https://www.codehub.vn/bai-viet).