# Laravel pagination returns links in http and not https

Tags: php, laravel, ssl, https

I am using the `->paginate(20);` function on my query but the only problem is that it will return http and not https

Eg: `"next_page_url":"http://www.mysite"`

I have tried to force my app to use https by adding this in AppServiceProvider

```
public function boot()
    {
        if (!\App::environment('local')) {
            \URL::forceSchema('https');
        }
    }
```

So have can I force Laravel to return all links in https?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19967788/laravel-redirect-all-requests-to-https

Comment: This is not a dupe. There are specific bugs related to laravel pagination that do not apply to the rest of the url/routing logic. Please do not mark questions as dupes if you do not actually know that they are dupes due to actual experience in the specific matter being asked.

Answer (score 3):

I got it working by setting path on the paginator:

**Laravel 5.1+:**

```
$results->paginate();
$results->setPath(''); // Will return ?page=2
// OR
$results->setPath(config('app.url')); // Will return website URL defined in .env file + ?page=
```

**Before Laravel 5.1:**

```
$results->paginate();
$results->setBaseUrl('https://' . Request::getHttpHost() . '/' . Request::path());
```

I don't believe its the best solution, but fixed my problem.

[Source 1](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-pagination-returns-links-in-http-and-not-https)
[Source 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28798341/9527560)