# Laravel 8 Jetstream email verification “invalid signature” 403

Tags: laravel, email-verification, laravel-jetstream

Not sure what parts to post. The change password emails seem to work fine. But when ever I click on the email validation email, I get the 403 error. and I have no idea why?
From User.php

```
   namespace App\Models;
    use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
    use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
    use Laravel\Fortify\TwoFactorAuthenticatable;
    use Laravel\Jetstream\HasProfilePhoto;
    use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;

    class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
    {
    use HasApiTokens;
    use HasFactory;
    use HasProfilePhoto;
    use Notifiable;
    use TwoFactorAuthenticatable;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'username', 'email', 'platform','password',
    ];
    from config\jetstream.php
    'features' => [
        // Features::termsAndPrivacyPolicy(),
        Features::profilePhotos(),
        // Features::api(),
        // Features::teams(['invitations' => true]),
        Features::accountDeletion(),
    ],
    namespace App\Providers;
    use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
    class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
    {
  
    public function register()
    {
        \URL::forceScheme('https');
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
    public function boot()
    {
        //
    }
    }

    Routes
    <?php
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
    use app\Http\Controllers\WeaponsController;
```

Web Routes
Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!

```
    Route::resource('weapons', 'App\Http\Controllers\WeaponsController') ->middleware('auth');

    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('welcome');
    });

    Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'verified'])->get('/dashboard', function () {
        return view('dashboard');
    })->name('dashboard');

    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('welcome');
    });
```

I saw another post where something similar happened only when via a proxy server. I'm using Caddy2, could that have anything to do with it? It's insisting I add more detail, but I've got nothing more to add.

Comment: check your `env` file does your `APP_URL`  match `domain` the request is coming in on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was the proxy server.  When I bypassed it, put a certificate directly on the web server it worked.  So I did some research along that route and discovered this:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/28798341/15361400
By Adding my proxy servers' ip address in the app\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies.php file where it says

```
class TrustProxies extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * The trusted proxies for this application.
     *
     * @var array|string|null
     */
    protected $proxies;
```

change this last line to say  protected $proxies = "Proxy servers IP address here";
took care it.

Comment: `protected $proxies = '*';` fixed it using this. I was using cloudflare's DNS proxy and gmail's SMTP to send verification emails. What would've been my proxy that I should've written there except the * wildcard? I am confused

Answer (score -3):

Just uncomment the Features::emailVerification() in config/fortify.php

```
'features' => [
        Features::registration(),
        Features::resetPasswords(),
        Features::emailVerification(),
        Features::updateProfileInformation(),
        Features::updatePasswords(),
        Features::twoFactorAuthentication([
            'confirmPassword' => true,
        ]),
    ],
```

Comment: the fact that the OP is clicking a link on the email means this has already been activated